# Why is " Date Modified" for files stored in .ZIP "off" by one hour after the DST switch?

Tags: datetime, timezone, dst, windows-explorer

So it's my understanding that NTFS stores "date modified" time stamps in UTC internally. I have written a C# application that is inserting this UTC "Date Modified" for files that have been extracted from a .ZIP into a database. Code:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(uri);
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = info.LastWriteTimeUtc;
```

One of our testers noted that the time stamp from the database appears to be off by one hour as compared to what is shown by Windows Explorer. Here is an example of what our tester is seeing in Windows Explorer:

[image: What windows explorer is showing on Nov 7th]

This is what the database is showing:

[image: DataBase Value]

As you can see, the DB says 1:03AM (UTC) where as Windows Explorer says 10:03PM.

To test this, I simply changed my system date time to Sat Nov 5th BEFORE the DST switch over. When doing this and re-opening the .zip (with NO changes to the zip whatsoever) I now see the correct date of 9:03PM:

[image: What I see after switching SYSTEM date to Nov 5th]

I believe this is due to Windows Explorer's time zone interpretation as I am fairly certian that the file modified date was 9:03PM EDT on Nov 5th and NOT 10:03pm. Can someone help me understand this phenomon in a little more detail?

BTW, sorry for blurring out the file names, but take my word that this is the exact same file. Also, FYI - I am in "EST – Eastern Standard Time" (UTC -5h) time right now.

Comment: It is the time of the year again.  The .zip archive format is quite old, goes back to the DOS days.  It stores local time, not UTC.  So this is entirely normal.

Comment: Haha, yep, it's this time of year! Okay, this is what I assumed. that this is unique to the .zip format. Interestingly, on some machines, when I extract the file from the .zip, the file's date modified displays correctly as 9:03PM where as on other machines it does not. Regardless, I can almost guarantee that the actual file modified date is 9:03 and that our DB is correct.